# Magento 1.9 - How to get OrderId & TotalOrderAmount from order successful page?

Tags: review, third-party-module, magento1.9.2.3, ecommerce-tracking

Here is my stamped tracking code,

```
<img src="//stamped.io/conversion_tracking.gif?sId=5967067hgtt78y&apiKey=3956785687857869756769hhuhyuhuy&orderId=##orderId##&orderAmount=##totalOrderAmount##&orderCurrency=INR" />
```

How to load magento variable ##orderId## & ##totalOrderAmount##?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit following file:

> app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/checkout/success.phtml

In above file, you already having order Id i.e $this->getOrderId()
based on Id you can get Order total like:

```
$orderId = $this->getOrderId();

$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->loadByIncrementId($orderId); // load order

$total = $order->getGrandTotal(); // order total with Shipping amount
$total = $order->getSubtotal(); // order total without Shipping amount
```

Now you have `$orderId` and `$total`

Hope above will help!

Comment: Instead of order id how to get order increment id?

Comment: How to simplify the code https://codeshare.io/5DqEwk

Comment: by above code, you are getting increment id by default. if you need order id you can use `$order->getId();` after load by increment id..

Comment: if you are getting something like `100000003` it is increment id and when you get id for this, it will be only `3`